# Checking user input for two key inputs

Tags: python-3.x, user-input

So I am asking the user to input '##' and a number (e.g. ##2) and once this exactly like ##2 the program can proceed. But I do not know how to check a user input for **two** inputs. I was thinking about using an **and** but I am sure there must be a better way to do it.

I have made it work for the '##' but for the number I don't know how I should approach this. But when I enter ##2 it crashes. I have used the split() method to try and fix it but it hasn't worked.

```
userInput = input()

def star_print(number):
    return number
number = int(userInput)
for i in range(number, 0,-1):
    print("*" * i)
while (userInput == '##':
    star_printer(userInput)
    break
```

Any suggestions?

Cheers

Comment: What is the expected output supposed to look like?

Comment: @mnickey The output should print the number of stars the number the user has entered. So if we did ##2 it will print ** then * on the next line.

Comment: OK, so what we're looking for is almost an inverted triangle?

Comment: @mnicky yes that's right.

Comment: This isn't very elegant but this might work for you. 
def star_print(number):
    return number

number = input()
##3

if '##' not in number:
    print('You need to prepend two # marks before your number')
else:
    print('Valid input, continuing')
    number = number.replace('#', '')
    number = int(number)

for i in range(0, number+1):
    print("*" * i)

*
**
***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't very elegant but I'm sure you can work with this and make it amazing.

```
def star_print(number):
    return number

number = input()

if '##' not in number:
    print('You need to prepend two # marks before your number')
else:
    print('Valid input, continuing')
    number = number.replace('#', '')
    number = int(number)

for i in range(0, number+1):
    print("*" * i)
```

`*`
`**`
`***`

```
for i in range(number+1, 0, -1):
    print("*" * i)
```

`***`
`**`
`*`